# How to make two independent ui-views using ui-router for one module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to make two independent ui-views using ui-router for one module.
The task is to make ui-views "know" where to place current state , making something like redirection.

[image: Page Layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, here is an example, giving each 'view' it's own named controller (imported in this case):

```
$stateProvider
  .state('content_one', {
    url: '/content1',
    views: {
      '@main': {
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        controller: StateOneMainController
      },
      '@other': {
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        controller: StateOneOtherController
      }
    }
  })
  .state('content_two', {
    url: '/content2'
  });
```

Then in your template you have

```
<div ui-view="main" id="main"></div>
<div ui-view="other" id="other"></div>
```